# What to do about MinGW missing Core Audio headers?

Tags: c, mingw

I'm currently trying to build a little C app using Eclipse CDT and MinGW, however I've hit a snag.

I'm looking for devicetopology.h among other header files which were introduced as part of the Core Audio API in Windows Vista.

**My question** is really "why are 4 year old headers still not in the mingw win32api" - not in the ungrateful sense but more along the lines of is there some technical reason why MinGW can't make use of those libraries?

Any missing defs that I've encountered so far I've just defined in my own source, but I'm apprehensive about importing an entire .h file and I'm unsure of where I'd even source such a file other than the Windows SDK which I imagine was designed to compile under VC. I've found a project called PortAudio (http://www.portaudio.com) which has the headers in their SVN but wished to **understand** the reasons why the headers aren't included in the first place instead of copy paste coding.

I'd just use VS C++ Express to solve this problem, however I missed some of the features which were gimped the last time I used the C# Express version.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm guessing that the headers and libraries for this set of APIs isn't in the MinGW distribution for the simple reason that no one has done the work to put them there. For copyright reasons, MinGW can't just put the Microsoft headers there - maybe they can pull the ones from the PortAudio project (I don't know). Even if that's true, *someone* has to do that work, even if it might be minimal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just found it a bit odd that no one had found the time in 4 years however, but if that is the reason then that is fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your last comment - what's missing from Visual C++ Express that you get from using MinGW instead?  Note that you can also drive the compiler included with VC++ Express (or the compiler that comes with the Windows SDK) from any IDE that supports driving a command-line build - which is what I'd guess you have to do with MinGW, too.

If it's debugging capabilities that you're looking for, the free Debugging Tools for Windows package that comes with the Windows SDK is quite capable (though the VC++ Express debugger is pretty nice, too).

VC++ Express doesn't have MFC, but then again neither does MinGW. So what's missing from VC++ that's hanging you up?

Comment: Thanks for your reply also :). It's not so much what I get out of MinGW it was more what I was hoping to get out of Eclipse. I can't talk directly for C++ Express however C# express had a gimped debugger, no conditional breakpoints, no integrated source control, gimped refactoring tools, intellisense seemed poor in comparison to eclipse's version accessed by ctrl+space. Perhaps C++ Exp doesn't have these little features I've grown used (5 years of Java dev). VC Compiler can be used in Eclipse CDT but you lose debugging support. I may check out the tools in the Win SDK though, thank you again.

Comment: I can see why you'd prefer the Eclipse IDE's editing/refactoring/navigation capabilities over VC++ Express IDE's. It's been  a while since I use Eclipse - I thought that someone was working on an Eclipse debugging connector to the MS cdb debugger API, but a quick Google indicates that that might not have gotten anywhere. That's too bad. It would be a nice (and free) combination.  I don't know the details of  MS debugger's API, but at least UltraEdit Studio and Qt Creator do it, so it should be possible in Eclipse (but then again, I'm not doing the work...).

Comment: Heh, I've just become used to Eclipse over the years really - the sad thing is that the full versions of Visual Studio do actually support the features that I miss but there I go. I may try out C++ Express and work around the little annoyances (external tools for source repos etc). I also found this thread which says that the VC compiler is apparently going to get increased support for Eclipse CDT some time around June 2011: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=199375&S=ae49a304f0b7fab12a83fd1e1c7e6d49#page_top